# Page table: Page fault

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory

I have a few questions regarding page tables, especially when a page fault occurs.

I understand that a page fault occurs when the CPU demands a page, but it is not present in the RAM, and has to be fetched from the swap space. The page table uses the higher order bits of the virtual address for indexing, and also contains an invalid bit that indicates if the page is in the memory.

Here is what I don't understand. Does the page table contain the physical addresses for those pages also for whom the invalid bit is set? I mean, they are not present in the physical memory. So, my understanding is that those pages for whom the invalid bit is set, the corresponding physical addresses should be blank. Am I missing something?

Another question is why can't we have entries only for those pages that are present in the memory. This way, the size of the page table can be made smaller.

Yet another question is that when the operating system swaps-in a page after a page fault into the RAM, is the physical address of the frame to which the page is assigned converted to virtual address for updating the page table?

Can someone please clarify these doubts? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that a page fault occurs when the CPU demands a page, but it is not present in the RAM, and has to be fetched from the swap space.

The triggering of a page fault generally is either a one or two step process. The fault is triggered by the state of the page table.

> The page table uses the higher order bits of the virtual address for indexing, and also contains an invalid bit that indicates if the page is in the memory.

The bit positions and usage are entirely system dependent. There are two levels of invalidity. (1) The page may not be mapped to the logical address space; and (2) the page may be mapped but has no corresponding mapping to a physical page frame (paged out). Those two checks could be indicated in the page table or in conjunction with mapping data maintained by the operating system.

> Does the page table contain the physical addresses for those pages also for whom the invalid bit is set?

If the page table entry indicates that there is a valid mapping for a logical page to a physical page frame, the page table entry  contains that mapping.

> I mean, they are not present in the physical memory. So, my understanding is that those pages for whom the invalid bit is set, the corresponding physical addresses should be blank.

This is not generally the case. If the page table entry indicates through its control bits that there is no mapping to a physical page frame, the processor normally ignores the actual mapping bits. This allows the operating system to use those bits to identify where the page is stored on disk.

> Another question is why can't we have entries only for those pages that are present in the memory. This way, the size of the page table can be made smaller.

You are describing an INVERTED PAGE TABLE. Some systems implement page tables that way. However, most system do not and they impose additional overhead on the operting system.

> Yet another question is that when the operating system swaps-in a page after a page fault into the RAM, is the physical address of the frame to which the page is assigned converted to virtual address for updating the page table?

The page fault handler needs to (1) allocate a physical page frame ; (2) load the data from secondary story into the page frame; (3) update the page table to indicate the logical page to physical page frame mapping; and (4) restart the instruction that caused the fault.

Comment: Hi, if every page frame entry has a copy in the secondary storage, and when is the time to make this copy.why can't just ignore it and create this copy only when the page frame is needed to be swapped out. wouldn't it be too costly to reserve copies for every page frames, especially nowadays with more and more physical memory.

Comment: `(2) load the data from secondary story` -> `(2) load the data from secondary storage`